# Using DATEIF only if another column returns 2 out of the 3 column entries

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I'm attempting to calculate the difference in dates (the current date & Date Opened column) only if the Status? Column reads Open or Hold.
I've tried:

```
=IF(Status?,"Open" OR "Hold",(DATEDIF([Date Opened],NOW(),"D")))
```

and

```
=IF(Status?,"Open","Hold",(DATEDIF([Date Opened],NOW(),"D")))
```

But get a syntax error.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula:

```
=IF(OR([Status?]="Open", [Status?]="Hold"), DATEDIF([Date Opened],NOW(),"D"), 0)
```

Instead of 0 you can put any default value you want if status is neither open nor hold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formulas:

```
=IF(OR([Status]="Open",[Status]="Hold"),DATEDIF([Date Opened],NOW(),"D"))
```

Calculated Field Formulas:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)